# While function issue

Tags: python, while-loop

i want to generate a random number and loop it until it matches my statement in python

```
import random as ra

random=ra.randint(0,100)

while random==56:
      if random==56:
         print('this is it')
```

i cant get pass it i am a beginer and as far as i have learned while loops are used to run the program until the condition is false

i did create infinite loops though xd

```
import random as ra

random=ra.randint(0,100)

while random>56:
      if random>56:
         print('this is it')
```

```
import random as ra

random=ra.randint(0,100)

while random==56:
      if random==56:
         print('this is it')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to trace through your code by hand.  If you did that here, you'd realize that `random` was never changing.  And it's a bad practice to name your variables after reserved words or standard modules.

```
import random

while True:
    rand=random.randint(0,100)
    if rand==56:
        print('this is it')
        break
```

Comment: thanks for the valuable feedback and help i got it the part where i got it wrong thank you for the help